# Vanilla Javascript how to display json response as plain HTML

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object which I want to display as a list.

So for that I've created a wrapper:

```
<div id="results">
   <ul></ul>
</div>
```

and my `javascript` looks like this:

```
let search_results = document.getElementById('results');
let results_list = search_results.querySelector('ul');

fetch(someApiUrl).then(response => {
    return response.json();
}).then(data => {
    
    let results = data.data;

    // THIS WAS MY FIRST APPROACH BUT IN ONLY RETURNED THE LAST ITEM 
    results.forEach(element => {
        results_list.innerHTML = element.name
    });

}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

the response is:

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "blabla"
},
{
   id: 2,
   name: "blabla"
},
{
   id: 3,
   name: "blabla"
}
```

so, how can I append an `<li>` for each item of the response?

Can someone help me out?

Comment: `results_list.innerHTML = element.name` ---> `results_list.innerHTML += element.name` - note that there adding elements to the DOM in a loop is not ideal and there are efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You should loop through the data and build the list elements. And in the end you can set the innerHTML to be the generated list:

```
let results = data.data;
let list = "";

results.forEach(element => {
   list += "<li>" + element.name + "</li>";
});

results_list.innerHTML = list;
```

Answer (score 1):

Recreating existing elements in a loop is expensive and error prone, create the elements with JavaScript, like this:

```
results.forEach(element => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = element.name;
  results_list.appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: You should also not append to DOM in a loop; you could create a container element before the `forEach` method and append `li` elements in that container element. After the `forEach`, you could append the container element in the `results_list`.

Comment: @Yousaf Yes, that's true, specifically when creating large elements with a lot of content. Though the difference is almost negligible, if you're not reading any layout-spefic values from the appended content in the loop. Applying this to OP's case, `ul` element should be also created dynamically, and then append the `li`s to that element, and finally append `ul` to the wrapper element, which already exists in the DOM.